# How to connect to a secured Kafka cluster from Zeppelin ("Failed to construct kafka consumer")?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read some data from a Kafka broker using structured streaming to display it in a Zeppelin note. I am using Spark 2.4.3, Scala 2.11, Python 2.7, Java 9 and Kafka 2.2 with SSL enabled hosted on Heroku, but get the StreamingQueryException: 'Failed to construct kafka consumer'.

I am using the following dependencies (set in the Spark interpreter settings):

```
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3  
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.4.3     
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3
```

I have tried older and newer versions, but these should match Spark/Scala versions I am using.

I have successfully written and read from Kafka using simple Python producer and consumer.

The code I am using:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when

schema = StructType().add("power", IntegerType()).add("colorR", IntegerType()).add("colorG",IntegerType()).add("colorB",IntegerType()).add("colorW",IntegerType())

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers) \
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/home/ubuntu/kafka/truststore.jks") \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", "/home/ubuntu/kafka/keystore.jks") \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", password) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", password) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("subscribe", topic) \
  .load()

schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([StructField("power", IntegerType()), 
                StructField("colorR", IntegerType()),
                StructField("colorG", IntegerType()),
                StructField("colorB", IntegerType()),
                StructField("colorW", IntegerType())]))

readDF = df.select( \
  col("key").cast("string"),
  from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema))

query = readDF.writeStream.format("console").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

And the error I get:

```
Fail to execute line 43: query.awaitTermination()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-2171412221151055324.py", line 380, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 43, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 103, in awaitTermination
    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 75, in deco
    raise StreamingQueryException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
StreamingQueryException: u'Failed to construct kafka consumer\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 2ee20c47-8293-469a-bc0b-ef71a1f118bc, runId = 72422290-090a-4b6d-bd66-088a5a534240]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nProject [cast(key#7 as string) AS key#22, jsontostructs(ArrayType(StructType(StructField(power,IntegerType,true), StructField(colorR,IntegerType,true), StructField(colorG,IntegerType,true), StructField(colorB,IntegerType,true), StructField(colorW,IntegerType,true)),true), cast(value#8 as string), Some(Etc/UTC)) AS jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))#21]\n+- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[tanana-44614.lightbulb]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]\n'
```

When I use read and write instead of readStream and writeStream I do not get any errors, but nothing appears on the console when I send some data to Kafka.

What else should I try?

Comment: Please remove `org.apache.spark:spark-streaming*` dependencies as they're not needed whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you, @JacekLaskowski - providing the fully-specified paths has helped. I am now able to connect to Kafka, but get the `Not authorized to access group: spark-kafka-source-ec67109b-c580-49fe-a97b-b762bb96db08--776798765-driver-2` etc. error. Because I have to create consumer groups before I can use them (a limitation of my Kafka hosting plan), I think I have to use direct streaming instead and specify `group.id`.

Comment: According to the official documentation, Spark doesn't have Python support for SSL communication with Kafka https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Kafka Consumer cannot access `~/kafka/truststore.jks` and hence the exception. Replace `~` with the fully-specified path (without the tilde) and the issue should go away.